# Twitter client for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, twitter

I'm looking for a twitter client for my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. I know there is a way to run one in Chrome, but I want it as a seperate program. So far I have tested the following:

- Hotot: won't let me sign in
- Choqok: signs in but does nothing
- Polly: crashes on startup
- Gwibber: gives a blank screen
- Turpial: gives an authentication error

---

Some extra software I have tried:

- Tweetdeck in Wine: installs but gives white screen back
- Pino: won't let me login and gives following error message:

  **403 Forbidden: the server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it**

---

Is there really no Twitter client that works on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04. I have just tried hotot and it won't let me login too. I had used it sometime back and liked it, so decide to see whether it's just your computer that has issues. Turned out it wasn't your comp but hotot.

Comment: you can use wine and rum tweetdeck

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Pino](http://pino-app.appspot.com/)

Pino is a simple and fast X11 client for Twitter and Identi.ca. It is compiled to native code, which assures small size and speed,

If it doesnot work you can run tweetdeck using wine if you really need a twitter client.

Comment: Pino doesn't work. It won't let me login:
403 Forbidden: the server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.

Comment: And tweetdeck just gives an empty screen in Wine..